# Bootstrap Navbar Toggle Not Opening

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have been trying to get the navbar collapse to toggle on and off, but it is not working.  I have made sure I include jQuery before bootstrap.min.js.  I do not know where else to look.

index.html

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block header %}


{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="wrapper">
    <!--=== Header v6 ===-->
    <div class="header-v6 header-white-transparent header-sticky">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="navbar mega-menu" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="menu-container">
                    <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' data-target='#myNavbar'>  
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Navbar Brand -->
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="">
                            <img class="default-logo" src="assets/img/logo3-light.png" alt="Logo">
                            <img class="shrink-logo" src="assets/img/logo3-dark.png" alt="Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENd Navbar Brand -->

                    <!-- Header Inner Right -->
                    <div class="header-inner-right">
                        <ul class="menu-icons-list">
                            <li class="menu-icons">
                                <i class="menu-icons-style search search-close search-btn fa fa-search"></i>
                                <div class="search-open">
                                    <input type="text" class="animated fadeIn form-control" placeholder="Start searching ...">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Header Inner Right -->
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <div class="menu-container">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <!-- Home -->
                            <li class="dropdown active">
                              <a href="/">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Home -->
                            <!-- Home -->
                            <li>
                              <a href="about" class="dropdown active">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Home -->
                            <!-- Home -->
                            <li>
                              <a href="/" class="dropdown active">Rockets</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Home -->
                            <!-- Home -->
                            <li>
                              <a href="/" class="dropdown active">Ballistics</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Home -->
                            <!-- Home -->
                            <li>
                              <a href="/" class="dropdown active">Space</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Home -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/navbar-collapse-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Navbar -->
    </div>
    <!--=== End Header v6 ===-->

    <!-- Interactive Slider v2 -->
    <div class="interactive-slider-v2 img-v4">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Test Splash</h1>
            <p>Fully responsive test template.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Interactive Slider v2 -->

    <!--=== Content ===-->
    <div class="content-md">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Service Box -->
            <div class="row text-center margin-bottom-60">
                <div class="col-md-4 md-margin-bottom-50">
                    <img class="image-md margin-bottom-20" src="assets/img/icons/flat/01.png" alt="">
                    <h1 class="title-v3-md margin-bottom-10">Fully Responsive</h1>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cur modo, tortor mauris con</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 flat-service md-margin-bottom-50">
                    <img class="image-md margin-bottom-20" src="assets/img/icons/flat/02.png" alt="">
                    <h2 class="title-v3-md margin-bottom-10">HTML5 + CSS3</h2>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cur modo, tortor mauris con</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 flat-service">
                    <img class="image-md margin-bottom-20" src="assets/img/icons/flat/03.png" alt="">
                    <h2 class="title-v3-md margin-bottom-10">Launch Ready</h2>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cur modo, tortor mauris con</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Service Box -->
        </div><!--/container -->



                    <!-- Link List -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
                        <div class="headline"><h2>Useful Links</h2></div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled link-list">
                            <li><a href="#">About us</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Latest jobs</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Community</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/col-md-3-->
                    <!-- End Link List -->

                    <!-- Address -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 map-img md-margin-bottom-40">
                        <div class="headline"><h2>Contact Us</h2></div>
                        <address class="md-margin-bottom-40">
                            25, Lorem Lis Street, Orange <br />
                            California, US <br />
                            Phone: 800 123 3456 <br />
                            Fax: 800 123 3456 <br />
                            Email: <a href="mailto:info@anybiz.com" class="">info@anybiz.com</a>
                        </address>
                    </div><!--/col-md-3-->
                    <!-- End Address -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="copyright">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>
                            2015 &copy; All Rights Reserved.
                           <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Social Links -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <ul class="footer-socials list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Skype">
                                    <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Google Plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Linkedin">
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Pinterest">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Dribbble">
                                    <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Social Links -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/copyright-->

{% endblock %}

{% block js_dependencies %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Web Fonts -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>

    <!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/style.css' %}">

    <!-- CSS Header and Footer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/header.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/footer.css' %}">

    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/animate.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/line-icons.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/fonts/font-awesome/cssfont-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/cubeportfolio.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/custom-cubeportfolio.css' %}">

    <!-- CSS Pages Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/page-one.css' %}">

    <!-- CSS Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/default.css' %}" id="style_color">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/dark.css' %}">
     <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/animate.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/line-icons.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/parallax.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/jquery.fancybox.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/owl.carousel.css' %}">


      <!-- CSS Customization -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/custom.css' %}">

  <!-- Web Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- CSS Customization -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/_Home/custom.css' %}">

    {% block header %} {% endblock %}

  </head>

  <body>

    {% block content %} {% endblock %}

    {% block js_dependencies %}
        <!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/jquery-migrate.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/back-to-top.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/smoothScroll.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/jquery.parallax.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- JS Customization -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/_Home/custom.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- JS Page Level -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/app.css' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/Responsive_Features/cube-portfolio-3.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                App.init();
                App.initCounter();
                App.initParallaxBg();
            });
        </script>

    {% endblock %}

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've got a number of duplicate CSS imports (`animate.css`, `line-icons.css`), what looks like a broken import (`bootstrap/fonts/font-awesome/cssfont-awesome.min.css`), and all of your dropdown menus have the "`active`" class (none should). If you get that cleaned up it'll be easier to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistake in your code . see this example for **Collapsing The Navigation Bar**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">           
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Bootstrap Navbar being displayed properly but its not getting clicked(hamburger menu), is that what you meant?